# TextField not submitting on Return with Android

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I have a simple app that takes a barcode input from the host and when it's done with the barcode it returns/enters.

When I run my app on an iOS simulator the enter key works fine with this TextField, however on my Android emulator, return does nothing and you need to actually click the tick to submit.

Is there a way to make the Android one work like the iOS?

```
new TextField(
  controller: _newBarcodeTextfield,
  maxLines: 1,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
  autofocus: true,
  onSubmitted: (newBarcodeInput) {

    _getProductInfo(newBarcodeInput);

  }
),
```

Comment: The code you posted works for me. Can you post more to see where the error comes from? You should also run flutter doctor and "Invalidate caches and restart" your IDE, just in case.

Comment: It just had something to do with my hardware keyboard and the simulator.

Answer (score 1):

I just added a `RawKeyboardListener` and listened out for **key 66** which is **return**. Don't know why `onSubmitted` didn't act the same as iOS so if someone knows I'd like to know.